# Get content of script iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I would like to get the inside of the `window.preload` from my script which is inside an iframe.

```
<div>
  <iframe>
    <html>
      <head> 
        <script>script 1 </script>
        <script>script 2 </script>
        <script>
           window.preload = {.....}
        </script> 
      </head>
    </html>
  </iframe>
 </div>
```

I think about adding an ID to the script but it's an external services so I can't modify the content of the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$.get(file_url, function(string){
   var html = $.parseHTML(string);
  var contents = $(html).contents();
},'html');
```

hope this will helps you.